# Can the time of gaining citizenship be reduced?

Tags: citizenship

The **minimum** time frame for getting Portuguese citizenship is [5 years](https://www.portugalist.com/get-portuguese-nationality/), and German citizenship is [6 years](https://www.germany-visa.org/immigration-residence-permit/german-citizenship/).

Can this time frame be reduced further?

Comment: You asked a similar question on the 7th of May, which contains an answer listing some of the conditions where the time frame can be reduced. [Is it easier to get a Portuguese citizenship if someone is an illegal immigrant?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/20422/17166)

Comment: For Portugal and Germany specifically? Or for any country?

Answer (score 2):

A residence requirement of 5 to 10 years is typical in the EU. There are several situations in which lower requirements might apply in some countries:

- If you are married to a citizen, it is sometimes possible to gain citizenship after less than 5 years, e.g. 3 years in Portugal, the Netherlands or Germany, 4 years in Italy or France.
- If you are refugee or stateless
- If you served in the country's military
- If you invest a significant amount of money in the country (e.g. Malta)
- If you are especially gifted or served the country in another area (e.g. athletes)
- If you formerly held the country's citizenship (e.g. Netherlands and Germany)

The absolute lowest residence requirement is 0 (e.g. immigrants from *francophone* countries or refugees in France).

Comment: i am talking about naturalization.

Comment: @user366312 Yes, that's what it is about. Technically, “reintegration” or gaining citizenship through  are slightly different procedure that might be called something else but all other examples are about speedy naturalization.